# UI Testing xCode 7.3 - Cannot print variables (i.e 'po app') in the console: (could not build Objective-C module 'Bolts')

Tags: ui-testing, xcode7.3

I have UI testing project set up and was working perfectly in xCode 7.2. Since I upgraded to xCode 7.3 I cannot print any variables in the console. I set breakpoints in both Application (main project) and UI Test, 'po' command works in the main project but as soon as it reaches UI testing the 'po' command stop working. I have tried almost all the solutions I could find on the internet but still no luck. It complains about the Objective-C module 'Bolts' that I am not using at all in UI testing. Below is how the error message looks like:

```
(lldb) po app
error: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module 'MyUITestProject' from AST context:
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "Headers/Bolts-umbrella.h"
        ^
/Users/../Pods/Target Support Files/Bolts/Bolts-umbrella.h:7:9: note:     in file included from /Users/../Pods/Target Support Files/Bolts/Bolts-    umbrella.h:7:
#import "BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.h"
        ^
/Users/../Pods/Bolts/Bolts/iOS/BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.h:14:9:     error: include of non-modular header inside framework module     'Bolts.BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController'
#import <Bolts/BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.h>
...
...
```

Is there anyone run into the same issue? Does anyone knows what cause this failure and any advice?

Comment: same issue for me, very annoying... :(

Answer (score 0):

Delete:

```
/Users/{User}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

and then restart your Xcode.